# Rewrite $eval method form angularJs in angular2

Tags: angular, angularjs, evaluation

I have a piece of angularJs code I need to rewrite in angular2.

```
$rootScope.$eval(expressionToInterpolate, allowedSetOfParameters)
```

Is there a way to do this or an npm package that can fill this void since $eval is not an angular function anymore?

Comment: whatever you wrote in eval expression, can be written as a normal javascript expression, so `$eval` expression needs to be reworked to pure javascript! If you got a particular expression to rework, please share that!

Comment: Its dynamic based on the api but here is an example: 'sprvsr_fair==disagree||sprvsr_fair==strongly'

Answer (score 1):

Below is an example of replacing the `$eval` logic with javascript

```js
// 'sprvsr_fair==disagree||sprvsr_fair==strongly'

function forgetEval() {
  return this.sprvsr_fair == this.disagree || this.sprvsr_fair == this.strongly;
}

const functionToCall = forgetEval.bind({sprvsr_fair: 1, disagree: 0, sprvsr_fair: 1, strongly: 1}); // bind can be used to tell the compiler to execute in the context, so all the variables are inside the 'this' of the function! 

console.log(functionToCall());
```

Comment: Hmm, but I don't have control over what the api sends me. Its hard for me to forget eval because 'sprvsr_fair==disagree||sprvsr_fair==strongly' is a string and the keys are undefined in my code.  Sorry I know its confusing, Im dealing with a bunch of legacy code. I have a lack of understanding of what the $rootScope.$eval method actually does so Im struggling to find a way to replicate it.

Comment: @blankpage985 checkout javascript [eval](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/eval) Note everybody says its evil, since if you execute random strings, user can upload, ur application will be in danger